# How can we open multiple IE instances while testing web appl. with selenium RC and java in eclipse?

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a test in Selenium RC with Java in Eclipse to browse two URLs. I get two Selenium windows, but testing of both URLs is done by opening one single IE window. How can I make it open the URLs on two different IE browsers and if possible, simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must use two Selenium instances to achieve this effect - one selenium instance per window.

Comment: Agreed.  If you start up two Selenium RC instances, have them operating on different ports, and then connect to the two RC instances from your test code.